# Backbone.Router accept query and path

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js, router, backbone-routing

I want that my Backbone.Router instance listens on hashbangs like '#/settings' and '#/settings/privacy'

Currently I handle this problem this way:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
         "settings": "settings",
         "settings/:query": "settings"
    },

    settings: function(query) {
        // do the routing
    }

});
```

I would now like to do this whole stuff in only one route. Unfortunately 'settings/:query' would only allow 'settings/'

Any one an idea how to handle this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options here. If you're happy with routes like `#settings/` (note the final slash) and `#settings/privacy`, then you can use this:

```
routes: {
    'settings/*query': 'settings'
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/m7ufD/

That won't work with just `#settings` though, the final slash is necessary for that route to work.

If you don't have any routes like `#settings-something-else`, then you could do this:

```
routes: {
    'settings*query': 'settings'
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MudaG/

That would also match things like `#settingsandstuff` and it would leave the slash in the route handler's argument (i.e. the function would get `'/privacy'` instead of just `'privacy'`).

The most flexible option is to use [`route`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) directly with a regex, then you can match `#settings` and `#settings/privacy` with a single route without either of the above problems:

```
// No routes, do it in initialize instead
initialize: function() {
    this.route(/^settings(?:\/(.*)|)$/, 'settings');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XGrQz/

That won't match `#settings-and-stuff` and it won't include the leading slash in the function's argument for `#settings/privacy`.